# React native setState array

Tags: arrays, reactjs, setstate

I need to change the state of an array element. This changing leads to change the color of the view, and an image. 
How I can change the state in react native and upload the changes?

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. My question is: are you changing some theme with fixed color and a static image, or the image url and color are dynamic?

Answer (score 0):

If you are changing the theme of your app (with static colors and image urls) it is better to handle it in css and save the theme's name in state, like this:

```js
class App extends React.Component {
  state = {
    theme: 'green-theme'
  }
  
  handleClick = () => {
    this.setState({ theme: 'red-theme' })
  }
  
  render(){
    const { theme } = this.state;
    return (
      <button className={theme} onClick={this.handleClick}>change theme</button>
    )
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'))
```

```css
.green-theme {
  background-color: lightgreen;
  /* background-image: url('path/to/img1'); */
}

.red-theme {
  background-color: lightcoral;
  /* background-image: url('path/to/img2'); */
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```